# Color of dim in tikzpicture

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to make all kind of different exercises on Thales. Changing letters ABCDEF and distances makes new excercises.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone} 
\standaloneenv{my}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-tab,pgfplots,tkz-fct,tikz-3dplot,rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows,arrows.meta,backgrounds,calc,decorations, decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.text,fit,intersections, patterns,positioning,shapes,shapes.misc,through,tikzmark}

\usepackage[locale=FR,exponent-product = \cdot,per-mode=fraction,round-mode=places,round-precision=1]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
 %%% THALES OEF 1
 \begin{my}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=15,ymax=9]
%\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\newcommand\puntA{A} 
\newcommand\puntB{B}
\newcommand\puntC{C}
\newcommand\puntD{D}
\newcommand\puntE{E}
\newcommand\puntF{F}
\newcommand\hoekEvenwijdigen{0}

%onderste lijn
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/L1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[L1](\hoekEvenwijdigen:14){LL1}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(L1=6,LL1=1) \tkzGetPoint{\puntA}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(L1=1,LL1=7) \tkzGetPoint{\puntD}

%bovenste lijn
\tkzDefShiftPoint[L1](90:5){L3}
\tkzDefLine[parallel=through L3](L1,LL1) \tkzGetPoint{LL3}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(L3=6,LL3=4) \tkzGetPoint{\puntC}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(L3=6,LL3=7) \tkzGetPoint{\puntF}
%middelste lijn
\tkzDefShiftPoint[L1](90:3){L2}
\tkzDefLine[parallel=through L2](L1,LL1) \tkzGetPoint{LL2}
%bepalen snijpunten
\tkzInterLL(\puntA,\puntC)(L2,LL2)  \tkzGetPoint{\puntB}
\tkzInterLL(\puntD,\puntF)(L2,LL2)  \tkzGetPoint{\puntE}
%tekenen van de evenwijdigen
\tkzDrawLines(L1,LL1 L3,LL3 L2,LL2)
%snijlijnen tekenen
\tkzDrawLines(\puntA,\puntC)
\tkzDrawLines(\puntD,\puntF)
%% Benoemen van de punten
\tkzDrawPoints(\puntA,\puntB,\puntC,\puntD,\puntE,\puntF)
\tkzLabelPoints(\puntA,\puntB,\puntC,\puntD,\puntE,\puntF)


%BEPALEN VAN DE LENGTEN
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntA,\puntB)\tkzGetLength{AB} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntB,\puntC)\tkzGetLength{BC} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntA,\puntC)\tkzGetLength{AC} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntD,\puntE)\tkzGetLength{DE} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntE,\puntF)\tkzGetLength{EF} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntD,\puntF)\tkzGetLength{DF} 

\tkzLabelSegment(\puntA,\puntB){\small \num{\AB}}
\tkzLabelSegment(\puntB,\puntC){\small \num{\BC}}
\tkzLabelSegment(\puntD,\puntE){\small \num{\DE}}
\tkzLabelSegment(\puntE,\puntF){\small \num{\EF}}


\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\num{\AC},30pt,transform shape}](\puntA,\puntC)
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\num{\DF},30pt,transform shape}](\puntF,\puntD)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{my}
\end{document}
```

Results in this:
[image]

But, I want to change the color of the lines and the text near AC en DF. I can't find how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes

*the labels DEF were not aligned correctly -- code edited as below

```
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](\puntD,\puntE,\puntF)
```

*for the dim AC

select a point A1 above A at right angles

```
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed](\puntA,\puntC) \tkzGetPoint{A1}
```

draw the thin red vertical from A to A1

```
\draw[thin,red,densely dashed](\puntA) -- (A1);
```

select a point C1 above C at right angles

```
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed, K=-1](\puntC,\puntA) \tkzGetPoint{C1}
```

draw the thin red vertical from C to C1

```
\draw[thin,red,densely dashed](\puntC) -- (C1);
```

define a point x which is located 70% from A towards A1

```
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(\puntA=3,A1=7)\tkzGetPoint{x}
```

define a point y which is located 70% from C towards C1

```
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(\puntC=3,C1=7)\tkzGetPoint{y}
```

draw a green dimension line from point x to point y with the dimension midway

```
\draw[green!50!red!70,thin,Stealth-Stealth](x) -- node[midway, fill=white,sloped]{$\puntA,\puntC$}(y);
```

Result

[image]

**Complete MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone} 
\standaloneenv{my}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-tab,pgfplots,tkz-fct,tikz-3dplot,rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows,arrows.meta,backgrounds,calc,decorations, decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.text,fit,intersections, patterns,positioning,shapes,shapes.misc,through,tikzmark}

\usepackage[locale=FR,exponent-product = \cdot,per-mode=fraction,round-mode=places,round-precision=1]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
 %%% THALES OEF 1
 \begin{my}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=15,ymax=9]
%\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\newcommand\puntA{A} 
\newcommand\puntB{B}
\newcommand\puntC{C}
\newcommand\puntD{D}
\newcommand\puntE{E}
\newcommand\puntF{F}
\newcommand\hoekEvenwijdigen{0}

%onderste lijn
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/L1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[L1](\hoekEvenwijdigen:14){LL1}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(L1=6,LL1=1) \tkzGetPoint{\puntA}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(L1=1,LL1=7) \tkzGetPoint{\puntD}

%bovenste lijn
\tkzDefShiftPoint[L1](90+\hoekEvenwijdigen:5){L3}
\tkzDefLine[parallel=through L3](L1,LL1) \tkzGetPoint{LL3}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(L3=6,LL3=4) \tkzGetPoint{\puntC}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(L3=6,LL3=7) \tkzGetPoint{\puntF}
%middelste lijn
\tkzDefShiftPoint[L1](90+\hoekEvenwijdigen:3){L2}
\tkzDefLine[parallel=through L2](L1,LL1) \tkzGetPoint{LL2}
%bepalen snijpunten
\tkzInterLL(\puntA,\puntC)(L2,LL2)  \tkzGetPoint{\puntB}
\tkzInterLL(\puntD,\puntF)(L2,LL2)  \tkzGetPoint{\puntE}
%tekenen van de evenwijdigen
\tkzDrawLines(L1,LL1 L3,LL3 L2,LL2)
%snijlijnen tekenen
\tkzDrawLines(\puntA,\puntC)
\tkzDrawLines(\puntD,\puntF)
%% Benoemen van de punten
\tkzDrawPoints(\puntA,\puntB,\puntC,\puntD,\puntE,\puntF)
\tkzLabelPoints(\puntA,\puntB,\puntC)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](\puntD,\puntE,\puntF)


%BEPALEN VAN DE LENGTEN
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntA,\puntB)\tkzGetLength{AB} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntB,\puntC)\tkzGetLength{BC} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntA,\puntC)\tkzGetLength{AC} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntD,\puntE)\tkzGetLength{DE} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntE,\puntF)\tkzGetLength{EF} 
\tkzCalcLength[cm](\puntD,\puntF)\tkzGetLength{DF} 

\tkzLabelSegment(\puntA,\puntB){\small \num{\AB}}
\tkzLabelSegment(\puntB,\puntC){\small \num{\BC}}
\tkzLabelSegment(\puntD,\puntE){\small \num{\DE}}
\tkzLabelSegment(\puntE,\puntF){\small \num{\EF}}

\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed](\puntA,\puntC) \tkzGetPoint{A1}
\draw[thin,red,densely dashed](\puntA) -- (A1);
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed, K=-1](\puntC,\puntA) \tkzGetPoint{C1}
\draw[thin,red,densely dashed](\puntC) -- (C1);

\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(\puntA=3,A1=7)\tkzGetPoint{x}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(\puntC=3,C1=7)\tkzGetPoint{y}
\draw[green!50!red!70,thin,Stealth-Stealth](x) -- node[midway, fill=white,sloped]{\small \num{\AC}}(y);


\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed,K=-1](\puntD,\puntF) \tkzGetPoint{D1}
\draw[thin,red,densely dashed,](\puntD) -- (D1);
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal normed, ](\puntF,\puntD) \tkzGetPoint{F1}
\draw[thin,red,densely dashed](\puntF) -- (F1);

\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(\puntD=3,D1=7)\tkzGetPoint{d}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(\puntF=3,F1=7)\tkzGetPoint{f}
\draw[green!50!red!70,thin,Stealth-Stealth](d) -- node[midway, fill=white,sloped]{\small \num{\DF}}(f);
%\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\num{\AC},30pt,transform shape}](\puntA,\puntC)
%\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\num{\DF},30pt,transform shape}](\puntF,\puntD)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{my}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, so no option to color the dim command?

Comment: have a look-- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567622/labelling-angle-issues/567764#567764 -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573451/is-there-more-compact-way-of-simple-

Comment: thanks, I prefer the solution you gave me in this thread

Comment: you may please accept the answer and upvote if it meets the requirement

Comment: I upvoted, but forgot to accept